# How to propagate error in OutputStream to client when using Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, outputstream, ktor

Is it possible to propagate an error in the output stream lambda to the connection. In my case it is possible for the producer of the output stream to generate some exception which I would like the client to know about. When I curl the below endpoint everything looks fine, as if "first\nsecond\n" was all the content successfully delivered.

```
call.respondOutputStream(
  status = HttpStatusCode.OK,
  contentType = ContentType.Text.CSV,
  producer = producer()
)
```

where producer() is:

```
fun producer(): suspend OutputStream.() -> Unit = { outputStream ->
  outputStream.write("first\n".toByteArray())
  outputStream.write("second\n".toByteArray())
  throw RuntimeException()
}
```

I have the same issue when using respondBytesWriter() and closing the channel with an exception instead.

Does ktor still send the final 0 byte for chunked http even if it encounters an exception in the OutputStream lambda?

Comment: So in other words do you want to make a server respond with the 500 status code if an exception is thrown in the producer?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to send a 500 status code since the headers have already been sent. What I would like is for the connection to be terminated ungracefully.

Comment: If you use the `Netty` engine you can respond with an instance of `OutgoingContent.WriteChannelContent` to send an empty reply from the server if an exception is thrown in the writer. Unfortunately, this behavior is inconsistent across engines https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3266.